# How to walk a directory tree on the classpath looking resource files?

Tags: java, spring

I have a collection of resources on the classpath something along the lines:

```
com/example/foo
    r1.txt
    r2.txt
    r3.txt
    bar/
      b1.txt
      b2.txt
      baz/
       x.txt
       y.txt
```

I know that this package is on the class-path sitting in WEB-INF lib, what I want to able to traverse the class-path starting at com.example.foo looking for all the .txt files. Call a function with siganutre similar to the following.

List files = findFiles("com/example/foo","*.txt");

I am using spring 3.1 so I am happy to use any methods that are part of spring.

**UPDATE:**
Solution using Spring based @jschoen suggestion below:

```
PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("classpath:com/example/foo/**/*.txt");
```

The spring matches using ant style patters thus the need for the double **

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Reflections library](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) if I am not mistaken.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage("your.test.more"))
    .setScanners(new ResourcesScanner()));

    Set<String> textFiles = reflections.getResources(Pattern.compile(".*\\.txt"));

    for (String file : textFiles){
        System.out.println(file);
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter what package you put, you just need one to start with, and it will find all the others.

EDIT: Also there seems to be [PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html#getResources%28java.lang.String%29) in Spring that you can use. It has a [`getResources(String locationPattern)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html#getResources%28java.lang.String%29) that I would assume you could use the pass the pattern `".*\\.txt"` and would work the same way. I don't have Spring setup where I am at or I would have tested it out myself.